# Docker ADD folder during build and then expose to VOLUME

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose for a basic web app.  When the image is built, it copies the static JS files in (`ADD`) and then builds them.

I then want to expose that directory to other containers, using `VOLUME`.

E.g.

Dockerfile

```
ADD ./site/static /site/static
WORKDIR /site/static
RUN gulp
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
    build: .
    volumes:
        - /site/static

http:
    image: nginx
    volumes_from: 
        - app
```

nginx.conf

```
location /static {
    alias /site/static
}
```

(Note, this is just an example)

The problem is that it seems to work the first time (i.e. when the volume does not exist), but is then never overwritten by the modified image.  If I was using purely a `Dockerfile`, I could achieve this by putting `VOLUME` after `ADD`.

Is there a way to allow this, or am I approaching it completely wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Possible solution 1

I might be wrong, but I think the trouble is that when (and if) you do

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up
```

your containers are recreated, and new "anonymous" volume is created.
You can check my guess running:

```
docker volume ls
```

I would try to use named volume, like so:

```
version: "2"
volumes:
  app-volume: ~
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/site/static
  http:
    image: nginx
    volumes: 
      - app-volume:/site/static
```

You need docker-compose 1.6.0+ and require a Docker Engine of version 1.10.0+ for usinng version 2 of docker-compose file.

### Possible solution 2

just

```
app:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./site/static:/site/static # maps host directory `./site/static` (relative to docker-compose.yml) to /site/static inside container
http:
  image: nginx
  volumes_from: 
    - app
```

And remove

```
ADD ./site/static /site/static
```

from your Dockerfile